# JQ error Cannot index string with number with scan

Tags: jq

I have error with scan function, why?

https://jqplay.org/s/E-0qbbzRPS

I need do this without -r

Comment: Please post your code inside your question. The link might become invalid in the future.

Comment: Link has successfully become invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your filter. Firstly, you need to separate parameters to a function with semicolon `;`, not comma `,`:

```
scan("([0-9A-Za-z_]+) == '([0-9A-Za-z_]+)"; "g")
```

Secondly, `scan` with two parameters is not implemented (in contradiction to the [manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#scan%28regex%29%2Cscan%28regex%3Bflags%29)).

```
jq: error: scan/2 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
```

But as you are using `scan`, your regex will match multiple occurrences anyway, so you may as well just drop it :

```
.spec.selector | [scan("([0-9A-Za-z_]+) == '([0-9A-Za-z_]+)") | {(.[0]): .[1]}]
```

```json
[
  {
    "app": "nginx"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/AVwv7kisxW)